# How to update the TabSpec

Tags: android

I have 3 tabs contain different contents. They loads content from Internet. I use 3 AsyncTasks to do it. 
At the beginning, 3 tabs show 3 ProgressBar. I want that everytime one task finishs, it updates the TabSpec and hide the ProgressBar. 
**The problem is I don't know how to update the tab spec.**

This is my snippet to create TabHost at the beginnig.

```
    final List<View> containerList = new ArrayList<View>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout.addView(progressBar);            
    }

    // Prepare labels and icons.        
    final List<String> tabLabels = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.destination_tab_labels));       
    // TODO Prepare icons here later.

    // Populate tabs' contents.
    final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    for(final String label : tabLabels) {
        final TabSpec tab = tabHost.newTabSpec(label);
        tab.setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            @Override
            public View createTabContent(final String tag) {
                // Return ListView here later.
                return containerList.get(i++);
            }
        });
        //TODO Add icon here later.
        tab.setIndicator(label);
        tabHost.addTab(tab);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 3 activities each with its own content, AsyncTask and progressbar. For any activity as the task finishes it will update its content and hide the progressbar.
Add these 3 activites to the tab host like ::

```
TabHost host = getTabHost(); 
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("TAB1").setContent(new Intent(this, MyActivity1.class)));
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("TAB2").setContent(new Intent(this, MyActivity2.class)));
host.addTab(host.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("TAB2").setContent(new Intent(this, MyActivity3.class)));
```

Comment: I did it! Thank you! After many hours implement your idea, I did it! My Tab is quite complex. Firstly I run AsyncTask to get categories from PHPAPI, then run 3 Activity as you said. In every Activity, I implement ProgressBar, run an AsyncTask to get its content from PHPAPI too. It's absolutely independent! Easy and clean!